# Is it possible to reconstruct generic return type with help of reflection - Java?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, types

I have the following code snippet (it is just example):

```
public class Class123 extends Thread implements Serializable, Runnable {
    public <T extends String> T callFriend(String name, Class<T> type) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get `<T extends String> T`?

```
method.getGenericReturnType() == "T"
method.getReturnType().getName() == "java.lang.String"
```

My second example is:

```
public abstract class Function<T, R> {

    public <V> Function<T, V> then(Function<? super R, ? extends V> after) {
        return new Function<T, V>() {
            @Override
            public V apply(T t) {
                return after.apply(Function.this.apply(t));
            }
        };
    }

    public abstract R apply(T t);
}
```

And I want to get: `<V> Function<T, V>`.

Comment: Since `String` is `final`, I don't think `T extends String` will be a particularly useful type parameter.

Comment: @DavidWallace, you are right. But, it is just example. I just want to get generic return type and type definition.

Comment: Then maybe you could construct an example that better reflects what you're trying to achieve.  Right now, it looks like you're trying to find out the class of `""`, which will always be `String`, no matter what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say you want this `<V> Function<T, V>`, then this is what you are looking for (I presume so because obviously the type gets erased)

```
    Method andThen = Function.class.getDeclaredMethod("then", Function.class);
    Type t = andThen.getGenericReturnType();
    ParameterizedType claz=  (ParameterizedType)t;
    System.out.println(claz);
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(claz.getActualTypeArguments()));
```

It prints:

```
Function<T, V> 
[T, V]
```

Similarly for your first case. Just as an example you can also do it for variables and not just methods:

```
class Outer{
  //Aim is to capture the type of generic type below. i.e. String
  List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
}
Field field = Outer.class.getDeclaredField("ls");
ParameterizedType p = (ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType();
Class<?> claz = (Class<?>)p.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
System.out.println(claz);
// prints class java.lang.String
```

Also this is a [class](https://gist.github.com/purijatin/a0486995c7df0e56b398) I wrote for myself, where it easier to capture the type of generic class. In case it helps